# Relationship between zero-pages and `smaps`

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

I have been trying to understand the different fields of the `smaps` file of a process, with special emphasis on which pages can add to multiple counters. For example, if a page adds up to `Private_Hugetlb`, it does not add up to `Rss` or `Referenced` because these fields are only touched by other entries.

Respecto to zero-pages, if I'm not wrong, transparent huge zero pages are completely ignored and you can't distinguish between having unallocated virtual pages with pages that have been allocated to a huge zero page transparently. Or that is what I understood by the following [piece](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4853c74bd7ab7fdb83f319bd9ace8a08c031e9b6/fs/proc/task_mmu.c#L589) of kernel code:

```
// From task_mmu, the file that implements, among other things, the `smaps` file
static void smaps_pmd_entry(pmd_t *pmd, unsigned long addr,
        struct mm_walk *walk)
{
    // [ ... omitted for brevity ... ]

    if (pmd_present(*pmd)) {
        /* FOLL_DUMP will return -EFAULT on huge zero page */
        page = follow_trans_huge_pmd(vma, addr, pmd, FOLL_DUMP);
    } else if (unlikely(thp_migration_supported() && is_swap_pmd(*pmd))) {
        swp_entry_t entry = pmd_to_swp_entry(*pmd);

        if (is_migration_entry(entry)) {
            migration = true;
            page = pfn_swap_entry_to_page(entry);
        }
    }
    if (IS_ERR_OR_NULL(page))
        return;

    // [ ... omitted for brevity ... ]
}
```

If a `pmd` entry refers to a transparent huge page of the VMA then the function above is called, which, if it discovers that the page the `pte` points is the huge zero page, the `page` local variable is set to an error and the function `returns` before adding anything to any smaps variable.

That implies that, if `Size - Rss - Swap = 2MB` in `smaps`, you don't know if you have 2 MB of unallocated space or a zero page. In other words, pages allocated to the huge zero page are indistinguishable from unallocated pages.

However, I haven't found a similar check regarding the special normal zero page. So, my questions is (regarding anonymous private VMAs):

If a page of my VMA is allocated to a special zero-page (be it huge or normal), to which "smaps fields" can that page add to:

- `Size:` always, since that's the size of the VMA.
- `Rss:` not for thbs (which adds to nothing besides Size), yes for normal vpages.
- `Shared_Clean:` logic says that if the vpage is allocated to the special zero-page, it should add to this field if there's at least other process pointing to it as well, but on the other hand, I think I read that the special zero-page has the reference counter deactivated for efficiency reasons and thus you can never know if there's more than one process sharing the special zero-page or not.
- `Private_Clean`: not for thbs (which adds to nothing besizes Size), yes for normal vpages.
- `Anonymous`: yes for normal vpages, not for thbs (which makes no sense, but still...)
- `AnonHugePages`: same, yes for normal vpages, not for thbs...

Are my comments/understanding correct?